# Separate mail section for POP mail account in Evolution

Tags: evolution

In Evolution, if I use IMAP as the incoming protocol for the mail account, then this account will have a separated section. However, if I use POP as the incoming protocol, then this account is merged into `On this Computer` group.
I want POP account to have a separated section. How would I do that?